# Ambiguous inheritance of abstract base classes:

Tags: c++

I have a far more complicated class structure than this, but boiling the problem down to its essence, this describes my scenario: I have two classes, A & B, that implement pure virtual base classes that share a common ancestor, and then a third class C that com-posits A & B. Finally, a template class that fills in the common methods in the pure virtual base:

```
struct I {
  virtual void r()=0;
};

struct A : I {};
struct B : I {};

struct C : A, B {
  void q(){
    r();              // the problem is here.
  }
};

struct D : C {
  virtual void r(){
  }
};

C* c = new D;
c->q();
```

My problem is, I can't see any way to get C::q to call r().

```
void C::q(){
  r();    // is ambiguous
  A::r(); // is pure virtual
  B::r(); // also is pure virtual
  D::r(); // C doesn't know about D
  ((D*)this)->r(); // is dubious and requires C to know about D.
}
```

How can I call the r() method from C so that the correct virtual method is called?

---

Sorry, I should have clarified that virtual inheritance can't be used here. I have found two solutions:

```
struct C : A, B {
  virtual void r()=0;
  ...
```

OR

```
struct C : A, B {
   using A::r;
   ...
```

Both appear to disambiguate the call to r() sufficiently for everything to resolve.

Comment: +1 for taking your problem and breaking it down to its simplest form.

Comment: Isn't r() going to be ambiguous in C without virtual inheritance ?

Comment: Did you mean virtual base class or just abstract base class? Because to make `I` a virtual base you need `struct A : virtual I {};` and `struct B : virtual I {};`.

Comment: @DumbCoder: r looks ambiguous to the compiler, but it is not. The only place its implemented is in D. This is the issue. @Charles: unfortunately this represents a COM inheritance issue, virtual base classes can't be mixed with COM.

Comment: `using A::r;` doesn't really help, at least the Standard says this will still be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redeclare method r as pure virtual in C:

```
struct C : A, B {
  void q(){
    r();              // the problem is here.
  }

  virtual void r()=0;
};
```

Comment: Not sure why this was the accepted answer. It is a hack. Correct answer is virtually inheriting from I.

Comment: Normally I would agree. But in my situation I can't use virtual inheritance. Of all the non-virtual inheritance solutions, this is the most elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Try virtual inheritance

```
struct A : virtual  I {};
struct B : virtual I {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell the compiler which part of the hierarchy to follow:

```
struct C : A, B {
  void q(){
    A * p = this;
    p->r();              // recent GCC compiles this
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous because the compiler doesn't know which `r()` to call, the one coming from A or the one coming from B.

The easy way is to write:

```
static_cast<A*>(this)->r();
```

or

```
static_cast<B*>(this)->r();
```

But I think that none of this is the answer you're looking for. You clean up the situation by inheriting through `virtual` the interface I:

```
struct A : virtual I {};
struct B : virtual I {};
```

Now, you can call

```
void C::q() { r(); }
```

as you would expect. The *simple* explanation of this is that, by using virtual, class C gets only one "copy" of the interface I, not two. This disambiguates your code.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using dynamic_cast rather than static_cast ? There are virtual functions involved.

Comment: No, you're going upward the hierarchy, not downward.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't overloaded r() in the child structs, so it's still pure virtual. i.e have no implementation.